# Android new intent creates a shortcut

Tags: android, forms, android-intent

When I create a new activity, and open it with the

```
Intent i = new Intent (this, Act.class);
startActivity(i);
```

Android creates an additional shortcut.
I do not want the shortcut. I want the application to have only one shortcut.

Comment: Check your `Act.class` code. Perhaps it contains the code which creates shortcut. Otherwise standard android implementation wouldn't do this.

Answer (score 1):

It is becauese you are Registering your Activity with category=Launcher in the Manifest File..remove that::

Only One activity should be registered with the Category of Launcher.

```
<activity android:name=".Test"
          android:label="@string/app_name">
     <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
     </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

Other Activities Should be Declare like this with no Extra Permissions.

```
<activity android:name=".Dashboard"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is done in your manifest. Only the activity with

```
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
    </intent-filter>
```

will show up in the launcher. Just remove these for activities you don't want to show up.

Answer (score 0):

In your manifest file i think you have registered your other activities with: using intent filter

```
 <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

 <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
```

only main activity should have above filters

for example

```
//Main Activity
<activity
        android:name=".SplashCalendar"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
// Your Other acitivties
    <activity
        android:name=".CheeckerWebView"

        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen" >
    </activity>
```